# How to setup routes for WebApi controller when controller is using generics

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

Here is my ApiController class which is using generics:

```
public class ValuesController<T> : ApiController
    where T : Foobar
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Here is the GET request:

```
<script>
    function refreshStatus() {
        $.getJSON('api/values')
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXhr) {
                alert('Message=' + jqXhr.responseText);
            });
    };
</script>
```

Here is the error response:

"{\"Message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64199/api/values'.\",\"MessageDetail\":\"No type was found that matches the controller named 'values'.\"}"

If the ValuesController is not built as a generic class, the GET completes successfully.  But when the generic  is added, the GET fails with the above error.

How should I setup the routing so that the client can successfully reach the ValuesController?

Comment: I don't think this will work, but how are you expecting that it will? Where will the generic type be determined?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a generic controller class? Maybe you should ask how to achieve what you need to do without the generic.

Comment: The existing operations accept generic entity classes and we are trying to expose them to other parts of code using WebApi.  I think you asked the right follow-on question about where the generic type will be determined.  I am now looking into extending the ValuesController<T> to provide that definition on the server side.

Comment: Using these two controllers I can now get the request routed through successfully.   public class ValueAController : ValuesController<FoobarA>
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value-1A", "value-2A" };
        }
    }
    public class ValueBController : ValuesController<FoobarB>
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value-1B", "value-2B" };
        }
    }